# Install cassandra PDO for PHP

Tags: pdo, cassandra, php

I've successfully ran the following:

```
apt-get install libboost-all-dev php5-dev libpcre3-dev pkg-config libthrift-dev
phpize
./configure
make
```

When i run the `make test` i get the following error and all tests are skipped:

> Build complete.
>
> Don't forget to run 'make test'.
>
> PHP Warning:  Cannot load module 'pdo_cassandra' because required module 'pdo' is not loaded in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: Cannot load module 'pdo_cassandra' because required module 'pdo' is not loaded in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Warning:  Cannot load module 'pdo_cassandra' because required module 'pdo' is not loaded in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: Cannot load module 'pdo_cassandra' because required module 'pdo' is not loaded in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to do 1 of 2 things, depending on how current your PHP is. If it is old, you need to install PDO first with

```
pecl install pdo
```

If you have version 5.1 or newer you just need to install the php-pdo package.
The PDO parent package needs to be installed so the pdo_cassandra can do its thing.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php